# How to make skyr more fluid

Tags: yogurt

I am currently trying skyr, an Icelandic yoghurt/cheese. I am preparing this mostly with fruits, nuts and cereals. I would appreciate if anybody has a suggestion on how to make it more fluid in order to be used as basis for recipes with pasta, meat or fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Skyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyr) is a milk-based product that is thickened with lactobacillae and similar bacteria and sometimes rennet. It falls in the same category as [yogurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogurt) and [quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(dairy_product)).

For thinning, use either water or milk (possbly cream for a richer taste), the latter keeping a more "milky" taste. Wikipedia states:

> In its traditional use, it was diluted with water when used as a beverage, or mixed with milk and crumbs of flat-bread as a quick meal.

If you want to use skyr for hot foods or sauces, be careful. Like yogurt it won't take heating too well and is likely to separate or curdle.